# IF ELSE, PHP and CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I'm just having a play around with a basic table with input from a form on another page.

I want to change the CSS of table in depending on the result of the game.

If the home team wins I want the background colour of the row to be gree if they loose then red, otherwise remain the same.

So I figured I'd need to use IF and ELSES, however not quite sure how to integrate that with CSS and where to put it.

I'm still very new with PHP.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Player Stats</title>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
  </head>

<body>

<h1>Player Stats</h1><br>
</br>
<h3>Results</h3><br>
</br>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Home team</th>
    <th>Away team</th>   
    <th>Score</th>
    <th>Venue</th>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["home"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["away"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["goalsh"]; ?> - <?php echo $_POST["goalsa"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_POST["formGender"]; ?></td>
  </tr>

</table>   
<br>
</br>


<a href="http://chrispaton.xyz/update.php">Update player stats</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Write the styles inside the PHP  and `echo` the CSS  you wanted, according to the condition.

Comment: You set the class based on your condition. You don't output CSS any differently.

Comment: But I'd need to calculate the difference between $_POST["goalsh"] and $_POST["goalsa"] though, right?

I.e. if $_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"] then CSS would display red background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to make two classes, red and green.

```
.red{ background-color: red }
.green{ background-color: green }
```

You could do something like,

```
<tr class="<?= (!($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"])) ? 'green' : (($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"])? 'red' : '') ?>" />
```

Comment: Sorry just to add orange in for a draw, I seem to be going wrong there.

I just added another condition to the same line, but looks like I have missed something out.

 <tr class="<?= (!($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"])) ? 'green' : (($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"])? 'red' : (($_POST["goalsa"] == $_POST["goalsh"])? 'orange'') ?>" />

Comment: Add this.
<?= (!($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"])) ? 'green' : (($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"])? 'red' : (($_POST["goalsa"] == $_POST["goalsh"]) ? 'orange' : ' ')) ?>

Comment: No it still doesn't like that... here is the full line I have! It was working perfect before I entered the orange.

<tr class="<?= (!($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"])) ? 'green' : (($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"])? 'red' : (($_POST["goalsa"] == $_POST["goalsh"]) ? 'orange' : ' ')) ?> </tr>

Comment: <tr class="<?= (($_POST["goalsa"] == $_POST["goalsh"])) ? 'orange' : (($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"])? 'red' : (!($_POST["goalsa"] > $_POST["goalsh"]) ? 'green' : ' ')) ?> </tr>